# BASH script. How to touch every file before a specified modify date

Tags: bash, find, touch

So I want to be able to go into a folder and update "last modified" data on every file within.

So far, I think I should be using:

```
touch --date "2012-12-31" /tmp/date
find /filestotouch -type f -not -newer /tmp/date
```

And this should list all the files that match.  Now, do I need to make a loop, or is there a simple way to pass this data to touch and have it do them all?

Comment: use the `-exec` switch to find

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There are two options:

1. Add the option `-exec`: ... `-not -newer /tmp/date -exec touch "{}" \;`
2. Pipe to `xargs`: ... `-not -newer /tmp/date -print0 | xargs -0 touch`

Comment: Both work, but yours was suggested first, so I feel obliged to give you the kudos!  Thank you.

Answer (score 1):

Try the find command:

```
find /filestotouch -iname "*.type" -mtime +60 -exec touch "{}" \;
```

The above commands will extract all the files that were modified 60 days back.

Comment: Edited: `{}` are special characters in some shells, so escape them by using quotes.

Comment: @AaronDigulla Nice one - this is the second time you are editing my post(s) - which is good. :)

Comment: Since the question asks for `-not -newer`, I think this should read `-mtime +60`. See